# tp link WA801ND wireless operation mode

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a TL TL-WA801ND from TP-Link. My goal is to improve Wifi signal on the ground floor in our house. The router from the ISP is located on the first floor.

I'm in doubt which mode I should use. The TP-link is connected to the wired network with an ethernet cable and should "convert" the wired ethernet to wifi (same network, same SSID, ...)

Comment: You're probably going to want "Bridge with AP" as this will create a new access point (read: wireless network signal) on the ground floor, that integrates seamlessly with your current network (i.e. it doesn't add another layer of NAT and DCHP.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up in Bridge Mode with AP:

[image]

1. To do that login to your 801ND
2. Click Network. Please make sure the access point’s IP address is in
   the same IP segment with the Root Router and avoid  the  IP
   conflict. Click Save.
3. Click Wireless ->Wireless Settings. Select Bridge with AP as the
   Operation Mode and your Region.
4. Click on Search button at the bottom, an AP list will be displayed.
   Choose your root AP and locate the BSSID (MAC address) of root AP,
   Click Connect, and then click on save button.[image]
5. Go to Wireless-Security Settings to secure the wireless as WEP. Type
   in exactly the same password as your root router’s  and click on
   save button.   Note: It only supports WEP when TL-WA801ND V1 is
   configured as bridge mode.
   [image]

Go to System Tools-Reboot to reboot the device or the settings will not take effect.